# How to change separate associative arrays to something usable such as one indexed array?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, associative-array

`print_r($element_attrs);` returns the following arrays which are gathered from an xml file.

```
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Increasing Clouds ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Thunderstorms ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Thunderstorms Likely ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Cloudy ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Mostly Cloudy ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Mostly Sunny ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Mostly Clear ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Sunny ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Mostly Clear ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Sunny ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Mostly Clear ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Sunny ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Mostly Clear ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Mostly Sunny ) 
Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Fair ) 
Array ( )
```

Right now they are 16 separate associative arrays in which all the keys are the same except for the last one that's blank for some reason.  What I'd like to do is return the value for the second to last array `Array ( [WEATHER-SUMMARY] => Fair )`.  I've been experimenting with `foreach()` and `for()` loops to try to create either an index where I can retrieve the array I want or make a multidimensional array that contains all the info for each array.  Everything I try treats each array as separate and doesn't allow me to access the data as a group.

Any help would be fabulous.  Thanks!

Comment: could you show what you have tried so far please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a little messy but I ended up using css to make all of them except the last one of each group invisible.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$weather_array = array();
foreach($element_attrs as $val){
    $weather_array[] = $val['WEATHER-SUMMARY'];
}
print_r($weather_array);
```

Comment: yes, I've tried something like this.  All it did was return the first letter of each value of each array as their own array `Array ( [0] => T ) Array ( [0] => T ) Array ( [0] => C ) Array ( [0] => M ) Array ( [0] => M ) Array ( [0] => M ) Array ( [0] => S ) Array ( [0] => M ) Array ( [0] => S ) Array ( [0] => P ) Array ( [0] => M ) Array ( [0] => P ) Array ( [0] => M ) Array ( [0] => A ) Array ( ) `